# PHP changes doesn't reflect : always_populate_raw_post_data = 0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php

[image]

I get this error on the installation of a magento instance.
in my php.ini settings I have changed the value 
from `0 to -1` 
and restarted apache2

It still shows this error

Comment: Use a `phpinfo();` call to check which `.ini` and settings files are being read.

Answer (score 0):

After googling to sometime I found out and confirmed that this was a php5 bug which is seen in several ubuntu and debian systems.

The only solution is reinstalling php. I purged my php5.6 and reinstalled it.

This is perhaps the simplest and fast way than to troubleshoot !

Good Luck !